# How to easily display a 12 by 12 matrix of input field for integers?

Tags: entities, blocks, wysiwyg, theming

I am still very new to Drupal. I need to let users create nodes to enter 12 by 12 matrix of numbers on one screen block. I don't really know where to start regarding displaying those fields (i.e. layout).

Is there a module/functionality helping defining the layout of those 144 input field in a square shape in Drupal? Some kind of WYSIWIG layout editor? Or, should I try to position those input fields with Javascript within a block?

Thanks.

Comment: Whatever the user enters in the matrix is just for display or there will be any processing you'll do on the numbers? Can you explain more as to whats the purpose of the node, matrix etc?

Comment: There will be some processing performed based on these numbers once they are stored in the database. Typically, the node content would be exposed via a Services for external application to fetch, process and put the result in a new node...

Answer (score 3):

Might be worth trying [CCK table field](http://drupal.org/project/cck_table) or [Table Field](http://drupal.org/project/tablefield)

Both seem to do a very similar function, I would give them both a try on a local dev environment

Answer (score 1):

if you're using drupal 7, you already have your work done using fieldAPI, its the part of core and you dont need to download any additional module. 
All you need to do is to create a content type and add a field to it using field API, now the creation of field is your job, you need to create a field which will hold the serialized data of first 12 columns. When finalizing the creation of your field, you will specify the number of field instances in the field creation form, and you can put 12 in it.
Now on the UI you can show 12 fields in columns whose serialized data will go in single instance of you field

Comment: you can even create you custom field using Field API which can contain 12 instances of 12 fields, but it would need a little RnD

Comment: I am ready to cover that extra mile if it helps, I have tech skills, just missing Drupal skills (I climbing the learning curve). Thanks for the pointer, I'll definitely investigate this option.

Comment: Unfortunately, one can only create 10 instances of a field in the creation form... I also need the users to be able to edit the cells...