# How to create a table field?

Tags: entities

Following an answer to another [question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/21512/how-to-easily-display-a-12-by-12-matrix-of-input-field-for-integers), I installed the Table Field module. However, I don't see them in the create field menu. How does one create such fields? Thanks (I am new to Drupal).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, my bad. I need to create that field instance in content types themselves.